# How to Optimize JSP loading by minimizing page load time?

Tags: jsp, optimization, jstl, page-load-time

I am working on a **spring mvc web project**.Application has a jsp page whose page load time is around 11 sec.I want to minimize it.

Page consists of some filters and the data of filters is rendered by jstl tags on jsp page.One of the filter has a list size of approx 4000 records.This results in response size of 2.7 mb. How we can reduce this response size?

I am using model.addAttribute("model",data) for maping data on jsp page and on jsp i use jstl looping to iterate that data.

Is there any way to compress jsp so that size of page reduces on network?

**EDIT**

**I solved this issue by lazy loading of data similar like facebook do on scroll bar.**

Comment: If there are many records then you can use pagination techniques for that.

Comment: Is the JSTL loop over 4000 records actually outputting something unique within each iteration of the loop, or are you just needing to loop through 4000 records to process them and do some math summarizations or data manipulations that don't require output?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.I have fixed the issue by lazy loading of data.